# SQL Self Join Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, self-join

I need to procedurally update a table by self-joining itself. Using SQL Server 2019.

```
CREATE TABLE Sect
(
     Section_Id INT, 
     Locale VARCHAR(10), 
     Record_Id INT, 
     Section_Id_1 INT
);
   
INSERT INTO Sect (Section_Id, Locale, Record_Id, Section_Id_1)
VALUES
(100, 'US', 1, Null),
(101, 'CA', Null, 100),
(101, 'MD', Null, 100)
```

The goal is to update the null values of `Record_Id` where `Section_Id_1` equals `Section_ID` with the matching `Record_ID`.

This is the intended result:

```
100|US|1|Null
101|CA|1|100
101|MD|1|100
```

I think I am close with:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET Record_Id = t2.Record_Id
FROM Sect t1
INNER JOIN Sect t2 ON t1.Section_Id_1 = t2.Section_Id
WHERE t1.Record_Id IS NULL
```

Appreciate your all's help.

Comment: What is your question actually ?

Comment: How do I get the "intended result"?

Comment: isn't your query already doing this ?

Comment: It's not on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: then show us on Fiddle

Comment: Your query looks correct.

Comment: I just don't get it; still not working. I tested on SQL Server with the following error:
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure crossRecord_Id, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 15]
There is already an object named 'crossRecord_Id' in the database.

Comment: We need a [mre] because nothing in your question mentions `crossRecord_Id` - one might guess you are creating a stored procedure, and that you have attempted to create it a second time when it already exists. But without seeing exactly what you are trying to do its all a guess. Is that what you meant by "procedurally update"? Because normally procedural is the opposite of set-based which is the opposite of a relational database.

Comment: Dale- Thank you. You made me look more closely and most of the error was (sleep deprivation) related to the SQL Server stored procedure that I had built. I kept looking at the live data, when I had made a test copy to play with... Such is life.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server 2019. But I think you don't need to use INNER JOIN, try this.

```
update
  Sect t1
set
  Record_Id = (select t2.Record_Id 
               from Sect t2 
               where t2.Section_ID = t1.Section_Id_1 
                 and t2.Record_Id is not null 
               limit 1)
where Record_Id is null
  and Section_Id_1 is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback. I just needed sleep. 
The final procedure is outlined as below.
...
UPDATE t1 
SET Record_Id = t2.Record_Id
FROM Test_Section t1
INNER JOIN Test_Section t2 ON t1.Section_Id_1 = t2.Section_Id
WHERE t1.Record_Id IS NULL
...

Enjoy your day!